# I am having trouble with rendering an object using the RTC rendering technique

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am trying to render a simple plane in THREEJS using the relative to center technique. When you start dealing with really big numbers on the gpu, like 6378137, the earth's radius, objects start to jitter due to floating point calculation precision errors on the GPU. One way to fix this is by rendering something relative to the object's center.

The basic idea is

1. make sure your position buffer contains vertices relative to the geometries center, which ThreeJS does by default. ex. for a point, 0, 0, 0
2. transform the center coordinates to center eye by multiplying the center by the modelview matrix using the cpu/double precision.

ex.

(mv00,  mv01,  mv02,  centerX,

mv10,  mv11,  mv12,  centerY,

mv20,  mv21,  mv22,  centerZ,

mv30,  mv31,  mv32,  mv33)

3. use that matrix in your shader to avoid any double precision multiplication (keeps values in matrix small and removes jitter for most objects)

I know that my modelview matrix is correct, because I have tested using that in the shader without RTC and simply translating my x coord by 6378137.

```
  <script id="vertex_shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
uniform mat4 mv;
void main() {
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mv * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

```
  <script id="fragment_shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
```

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 50, 50 );
let material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
  side:THREE.DoubleSide,
  wireframe:true,
  vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertex_shader').textContent,
  fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragment_shader').textContent
})
material.uniforms.mv = {
  type:'m4',
  value: new THREE.Matrix4()
}
var plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
plane.onBeforeRender = (renderer, scene, camera, geometry, material) => {
  let mv = new THREE.Matrix4();
  //calculate modelview matrix w/ view x modelmatrix
  mv = mv.multiplyMatrices(camera.matrixWorldInverse, plane.matrixWorld);
  let center = new THREE.Vector4(6378137, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  //multiply mv by center
  center.applyMatrix4(mv);
  let newMV = new THREE.Matrix4().set(mv.elements[0], mv.elements[4], mv.elements[8], center.x,
                              mv.elements[1], mv.elements[5], mv.elements[9], center.y,
                              mv.elements[2], mv.elements[6], mv.elements[10], center.z,
                              mv.elements[3], mv.elements[7], mv.elements[11], mv.elements[15]);

  material.uniforms.mv.value = newMV;
}
scene.add( plane );
```

For some reason, this renders the scene with the plane facing the wrong way, so it looks like a straight line.

*The error was in my set() method for matrix4, i just needed to read the modelview matrice's values in column-major format. I updated the code so it is correct now.

Comment: *someone else answered then deleted the answer it seems, but they were very close, so whoever that was comment and i will try and give you credit. The error was in my set() method for matrix4, i just needed to read the modelview matrice's values in column-major format

Comment: The answer was wrong which is why it was deleted. Three.js stores matrices with position in elements 12,13,14 but like many inconsistencies in Three.js the `Matrix4.set` function expects position in arguments 3,7,11

Comment: okay, I will leave this up for anyone who needs it for future reference i guess... for anyone else's reference, RTC reduces jittering for up to 1cm accuracy, but your object should not exceed a bounding radius of about 131,071 meters, which is okay for most things. if you need something bigger you should look up rendering relative to eye on the cpu/gpu.

-source: https://www.virtualglobebook.com/

Comment: For better precision you should consider adding `precision highp float;` at the beginning of your shader.